# MySQL with ON condition from another table

Tags: mysql

Let's say that I have:

```
SELECT * FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON b.c_id = c.id
```

Now what I want to do is to select b's that are assigned to c that is e. g. active (c.active = 1). How can I do that with ON?

Note that I can't use WHERE after the whole query above, because I want a's to be returned even if 0 b's are found.

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON b.c_id = c.id and c.active = 1`

Comment: This is incorrect and will return b's with empty c's and I don't want b's to be returned if c's are empty

Comment: Share the tables with data and the expected result, just by looking at the query what you need is very hard to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, I understood the question: You want all rows where either c.active equals 1 or where there is no entry in b or c, right?

It's a bit lengthy but this seems to work:

```
SELECT * FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.aid = b.aid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON b.bid = c.bid 
WHERE a.aid NOT IN (
    SELECT a.aid FROM a 
    INNER JOIN b ON a.aid = b.aid 
    INNER JOIN c ON b.bid = c.bid 
    WHERE NOT c.active
);
```

I could also imagine a solution using `UNION`

Comment: Yeah something like that but in this case using subquery equals just making a second, simplier query. I was just wondering if this is possible  to be done within one query

Answer (score 0):

Which rows are returned in each case...  Note that one case is different:
`FROM b JOIN c ON ... AND c.active=1` -- rows in both tables exist and active
`FROM b JOIN c ON ... WHERE c.active=1` -- ditto
`FROM b LEFT JOIN c ON ... WHERE c.active=1` -- ditto
`FROM b LEFT JOIN c ON ... AND c.active=1` -- all b's, but NULLs for inactive/missing c's
(Caveat:  I am not sure I got the cases correct; just keep in mind that ON and WHERE are *not always* interchangeable.)

When mixing JOIN and LEFT JOIN, you *may* need to add parentheses:
`FROM a JOIN ( b LEFT JOIN c ON... ) ON ... WHERE ...`
`FROM ( a JOIN b ON ... ) LEFT JOIN c ON... WHERE ...`